# WCF developed in 4.0

Tags: c#, wcf, iis, iis-7, iis-6

I have developed my WCF in 4.0 and still it is hosted in IIS 7.

Suddenly the Client requirement changes and now wants to host in IIS 6.

Will I face some hosting problem?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I'm aware you can host a .NET 4 WCF Application in IIS6 but you are limited to HTTP binding.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about this but for .NET 4.0, you might have some problems on running IIS 6 since single application pool can’t use for two different frameworks whereas IIS7 can create Application Pool targeting different framework.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it if its a normal `HTTP` binding full detailed explanation is [here](http://forums.iis.net/t/1163873.aspx/1)